# How do you create a constructor with two integers that never equal each other without using a builder, static constructor, or throwing an exception?

Tags: java, constructor

I am getting the eery feeling that code starts to get exponentially more complicated when constructors are not written correctly. Lately, I've been trying to simplify and stick to oop principles at the lower levels so that the code does not grow into a complicated spiderweb.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181850/are-exceptions-an-oop-concept

The question I'm asking may not be possible.

```
public class Foo
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Foo(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

always this ----> `foo.getX() != foo.getY();`

Comment: You simply can't. The only way to guarantee that two integers aren't equal is to accept one, and derive the second from it, e.g. by adding one.

Comment: Equality of non-constants can only be determined at runtime anyway.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - "Equality of non-constants can only be determined at runtime." seems to be an important rule I should keep in mind while designing, no?

Comment: Throwing an exception is really, truly the correct behavior here.

Comment: @KeepAtIt: I don't know about that. What's important is that a constructor should never complete successfully unless the object is in a valid state. Throwing an exception is a valid and important tool to ensure this invariant. Builders and static "constructors" are also tools for validly constructing more complex objects that would be difficult, inconvenient, or just plain ugly to create solely through a constructor.

Comment: You can guarantee that `foo.getX() != foo.getY();` if you do not mind checking and changing the input numbers.

Comment: @AndyTurner : Can you write your first comment as an answer, so I can accept it as the answer and close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't.

The only way to guarantee that two integers aren't equal is to accept just one and derive the second from it in a way that guarantees inequality, e.g. by adding one.

```
    public Foo(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = x + 1; // guaranteed not to be equal to x.
    }
```

But if you need to accept two values (e.g. because you need more flexibility than them being just one apart), the only reasonable thing to do is to throw an exception when they are equal.